# .onload issue with images / Firefox Android

Tags: php, ajax, image-resizing, firefox-android

There was an update for Firefox Android which got released yesterday and it seems to have caused a script we have been using to resize and upload images via ajax from working.

It's not my own script, it was implemented by somebody who previously worked for the company I am with, being honest it pretty much looks like a cut and paste of something they found online with a few additions.

It appears to stop working when .onload is called (so in this case image.onload = function(){ // check image and resize }). as a test I tried a few similar scripts and they all fail on .onload as well. I tried the remote debugger in firefox but it doesn't appear to give any errors.

It worked fine up until the update and it still works fine in Chrome and I have tried Opera as well and it works fine on that, so its not even critical, but its just got me a bit perplexed.

Just wondered if anybody knows whether it is likely to be a Firefox bug or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with Firefox 84 (tested on Android 10)
On bigger images (tried with a 6MB) onload and onerror never fires, works fine with smaller images..

```
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = reader.result;

      image.onerror  = function () {

        console.log('error')
      }
      
      image.onload = function () { console.log('loaded')}
```